# How to handle maven versions in a multi module project?

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I have a maven project infrastructure like this:

```
/trunk/all/pom.xml
/trunk/all/libs/lib1/pom.xml
               /lib2/pom.xml
               ...
/trunk/all/projects/p1/pom.xml
                   /p2/pom.xml
                   ...
```

You see, I have a lot of libraries and a lot of projects using these libraries.

All this is combined to one multi module project, because I like to

- import the top project into eclipse and have all my libraries and projects available at once
- only do a single `mvn test` to compile and test all my code after I've done some global refactorings.

Currently, all my modules are version `1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Now I want to release project `p2` and all libs `p2` uses (e.g. `lib1` and `lib2`) to version `1.0`. After that I do some code modifications on `lib1`, but **none** on `lib2`.

I want the next release of `p2` being version `1.1`, using `lib1` in version `1.1` (it was modified since the last release), but `lib2` still in version `1.0` (since it wasn't modified).

More general: If I do a release, I want to increase the minor numbers of the project being released and of all **changed** libraries since the last release.

#### Question

Do I have to take care for all the module versions by myself or is there a plugin that is able to do the required work for me?

Answer (score 8):

> Do I have to take care for all the module versions by myself or is there a plugin that is able to do the required work for me?

Well, if you don't want to keep the versions of the various artifacts (projects, libs) in sync with the version defined in `all/pom.xml` (i.e. just inherit it through the whole hierarchy), I'm afraid you'll have to start to manage them manually. I'm just not sure to understand why you wouldn't bump the version of say `lib2` even if you didn't make any change to it. With your current svn repository structure, all artifacts have the **same release lifecycle** somehow (when you'll tag the trunk, you'll tag everything in it).

Now, if `p1` and `p2` (I'll ignore the libs for the sake of simplicity) have **an independent release cycle**, I would recommend a multiple "trunk/tags/branches" structure as described in [this thread](http://markmail.org/message/f6qjdc7r3e7txqrz):

> ```
> myrepo
>   + .links (2)
>     + trunks
>       + pom.xml
>   + parent-pom (1)
>     + trunk
>       + pom.xml
>   + project-A
>     + trunk
>       + pom.xml
>   + project-B
>     + trunk
>       + pom.xml
> ```
>
> 1) The parent POM of the project has
>   an own release cycle. Every
>   component's POM will use it as parent
>   (referenced simply with `groupId` and
>   `artifactId`, no `relativePath`). For
>   a release you'll have to release the
>   parent POM first.
>
> 2) This is a construction to enable
>   easy check outs of a specific branch
>   of the project i.e. normally the
>   trunk. A subversion user checks out
>   myrepo/.links/trunk to get the head
>   revision of all sources. The trick is,
>   that that directory contains
>   external links (i.e. with the
>   [`svn:externals`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) property) to the
>   trunks of all other modules of this
>   project (parent-pom, project-A,
>   project-B). The pom.xml in this
>   directory is never released, it
>   contains simply a modules section for
>   the three modules to enable a multi
>   module build. With this construct
>   you're able to setup easily branches
>   e.g.:
>
> ```
> myrepo
>   + .links
>     + branch-2.x
>       + pom.xml
> ```

I've used this setup many times (I already wrote about it here on SO, see the related questions below), it works very well. Actually, many projects, including Maven, are using this approach, it's not a fantasy one.

This will not solve your "automagic" version handling (I don't know any solution for that) but at least, this structure plays nicely with the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/index.html) and would support your independent release cycle requirements.

#### See also

- [Building Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-building-m2.html)
- [XWiki Platform Structure](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/SourceRepository#HXWikiPlatformStructure)
- [Cargo SVN](http://cargo.codehaus.org/SVN)

#### Related questions

- [Maven parent pom vs modules pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom/2002304#2002304)
- [Migrating to maven from an unusual svn directory structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581877/migrating-to-maven-from-an-unusual-svn-directory-structure/1583343#1583343)

Comment: In my last project, I built a command line tool that let you automatically increment or decrement major, minor or increment version of a specific module while automatically updating all dependencies to it in other modules (it understood dependencies, parents and even artifactItems). It was great fun to use, but eventually we realized that we don't need individual module versions and so we ditched it. Great answer btw (+1)

Comment: @seanizer Interesting, although I didn't really need this granularity so far. Written in Groovy? :)

Comment: No, plain java. used no maven code, either. I'll see if I can find it and post it somewhere.

Comment: @pascal: Thanks for your answer, I'll rethink my current directory structure. But I think your suggestion is more work to maintain. With my structure I tag the whole structure when releasing a single project. That's all I have to do. The version numbers of the modules shall only give my customers an idea which part of the code (which modules) have changed.

Comment: @tangens: You're welcome. I'm not sure to understand if you are using the maven-release-plugin or not, my answer was maven-release-plugin oriented (as suggested by the tag). I'm also not sure to understand why changing the version numbers of modules is a concern for customers (you might have good reasons but why not using release notes?) but moving to manual version management conflicts with your maintenance concerns, IMO.

Comment: @pascal: I've tried the release plugin, but I've found no way to use it like I wanted/ needed it. Right now, the version numbers are a 'nice to have', but I could life without them if I'd have to manage them manually.

Comment: @pascal: My customers asked for version numbers, because they could focus their tests on modules that changed.

Comment: @tangens: I hope they are ready to pay for the generated overhead :)

Answer (score 2):

HI!
Maybe I'm missing something, but if your libs/modules start feeling the need to have their own version numbers, isn't that an indication that they are growin up and taking on a life of their own - i.e. becoming separate-ish projects in their own right?

Meaning it might make sense to treat them as such - treat them as separate projects, pushed to some mvn repo, and added to the core project as normal dependencies?

Sorry if I'm missing the point somehow, but I've been running into multi-module project "issues" myself....and maybe the issue isn't really an issue at all?

Comment: Each lib already has its own life. I'm looking for an automatical way to increase the version number of a library if it is changed since the previous release of a project using it. The point is, that I want to release the newest sources of all libraries together with the project.